# Loading numpy structured array saved in python3 in python2

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

It does not appear to be possible to load numpy structured arrays saved in python3 within python2 because the field names are unicode strings.

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
>>> a = np.zeros(4, dtype=[('x',int)])
>>> np.save('a.npy', {'a': a})
>>> 
$ python2
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
>>> np.load('a.npy')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 393, in load
    return format.read_array(fid)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 602, in read_array
array = pickle.load(fp)
ValueError: non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling
```

This has been a numpy bug for quite some time:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2407

Does anyone have a work around to be able to load numpy structured arrays from python3 in python2 (without having to load and re-save in python3)?

Comment: You're running into this problem because of the strange way you save the array. Why the dictionary `{'a': a}`? If you use `np.save('a.npy', a)` it loads fine in Python 2. If it's because you like to store multiple arrays in a single file, you should really be using `np.savez`.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to store multiple arrays in a single file. I have now changed over to `np.savez`

Comment: The numpy issue was fixed eventually, so, using `numpy 1.16.*`, `Python 2` *can* unpickle a numpy struct array that was pickled in `Python 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a `unicode` field name issue.

In python3 I can save an `object` array:

```
In [133]: b=np.array([[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]])
In [134]: np.save('a.npy',b)
In [135]: np.load('a.npy')
Out[135]: array([[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]], dtype=object)
```

in python2

```
In [260]: np.load('a.npy')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-260-76b2da2985df> in <module>()
----> 1 np.load('a.npy')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in load(file, mmap_mode)
    386                 return format.open_memmap(file, mode=mmap_mode)
    387             else:
--> 388                 return format.read_array(fid)
    389         else:
    390             # Try a pickle

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.pyc in read_array(fp)
    451     if dtype.hasobject:
    452         # The array contained Python objects. We need to unpickle the data.
--> 453         array = pickle.load(fp)
    454     else:
    455         if isfileobj(fp):

TypeError: must be char, not unicode
```

The error isn't in quite the same place, but it still involves `pickle.load`.  I get the same error if I save `{'a':a}`.

With the dictionary wrapper, python3 `load` gets

```
array({'a': array([(0,), (0,), (0,), (0,)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<i4')])}, dtype=object)
```

As `moamingsun` points out, if you save the `a` array without the dictionary wrapper, the python2 load works fine.

The problem isn't with field names, but with Python 3 v 2 pickling. `np.save` passes the buck to `pickle` if it has to save Python objects.  I'm sure the py2 v 3 pickling compatibility has been discussed in depth elsewhere.